# What is the sum of one + one in a 26 letter number system

Tags: arithmetic

A number system based on 26 uses the letters of the alphabet as its digits, with $A = 0, B = 1, C = 2, D = 3, E = 4, . . . , Y = 24,$ and $Z = 25. $
What is the the sum: ONE + ONE = in this system

Answer (score 1):

you have to do this sum as you would make it in decimal base, that is, coloumnwise

```
E+E=4+4=8=I
N+N=13+13=26=BA
B+O+O=1+14+14=29=BD
```

So the result is
BDAI

Answer (score 1):

We know that $$ 1+1=2$$

This can be represented in your system as

$$B+B=C$$

Now consider the number 32 it can be written as $25+7$ which is equivalent to AH.

Now consider the number 53 this can be written as $ 25+25+3$ which is equivalent to BD.

Comment: Please can you come up with an algorithm to this with an end solution

Comment: Do you mean conversion algorithm. I will try to find it out

Comment: If you want to convert number from decimal system to your number system then the hint is to divide the number by 25.

Comment: if the numbber is divided by 25 and has a remainder then what becomes of the remainder